# How to configure IBM WAS SystemOut logging to customize logging for each application?

Tags: java, logging, websphere

I have 4 appllications (ear) on my WAS. I need them to write in SystemOut.log some sign. I.e each application must write to log file its own sign. For example:

[16.01.17 3:50:05:592 GMT+05:00] **ADMIN** 000005e0 SubsystemMess I com.docflow.core.integration.jms.SubsystemMessageListener onMessage_aroundBody0 Subsystem integration message ID:f5392a5ec3b3f41502095b00110a134f0000000000000001 of type DP_EKS_BANK_GUARANTEE_RECEIVED process finished

Here **ADMIN** is sign of the application.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to adjust the default logging format in this way.  Your options would be to use java.util.logging.Logger with a particular name (to replace the "SubsystemMess" part) or to use a separate logging package and configure it to log to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Look at log4j and configuring each app's log4j to go to a different file.
Log4j's file appender can be configured to also include timestamp and more.

The only catch is you can't configure it from WAS's admin console then.

Note that java.util.Logger writes to the trace.log. If you use a different logger name, it will list as such in the same trace.log file. Upside is you can now configure it from the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution could be to switch to [HPEL logging](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ctrb_HPELOverview.html). Then you could query log entries for your given application using [logviewer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rtrb_logviewer.html), like:

```
logViewer.sh -includeExtensions appName=PlantsByWebSphere
```

I know that it is not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe it will be sufficient for your needs.